ffmpeg combine audio/ video output bitrate ratio
I attempted to combine the audio and video using ffmpeg, and I set the output bit rate, for example,
ffmpeg -i Testing_6_11_2024_12_13_08_AM.mp4 -b:a k output_video.mp4 -b:v k bufsize k maxrate k
The output file bitrate that I obtained was close to or less than the bitrate that was specified in the command. I'm not able to attain the precise bit rate that I specified in the command.
Is this the expected behavior
e.g.: input video bitrate:50000k
output bitrate mentioned in the command is:20000k
Observed Result : 15000k-17000k
actual command
combineFinalAudioAndVideoProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"-loglevel error -threads 0 -y -i ""{0}"" -i ""{1}"" {2} -b:v {3} {4} -b:a {5} -maxrate {6} -bufsize {7} ""{8}""",
videoSpotRenderParams.SlateVideo_Video_FilePath, videoSpotRenderParams.SilenceAudioFilePath, videoCodec, maxVideoBitRateAllowed * 1000, audioCodec, 320000, maxVideoBitRateAllowed * 1000, maxVideoBitRateAllowed * 5000, videoSpotRenderParams.OutputVideoFilePath);

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A 50,000k bitrate?  What is the actual command you're using?

a) yes, for most encoders, target bitrate is approached not achieved, b) however, if your command snippet is accurate, you've placed the bitrate parameters after the output URL. Which won't have any effect, They should be before.
